# TypeError: Cannot set property 'schedule' of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I'm making a scheduling application with React.js, and have a scheduling interface where users are supposed to select their availability with a draggable scheduling feature.  The feature works fine, barring a single error message: TypeError: Cannot set property 'schedule' of null.

The 'schedule' array is where I want to put the scheduling data, however I initialize it as [] because it doesn't have a set length initially (users are supposed decide this).  I've read about similar error messages on StackOverflow, but they didn't seem to help resolve my specific issue.

Here's the relevant code with the error message:

```
import Welcome from "../../../components/welcome";
import React, {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {useAuth} from "../../../lib/authlib";
import {post} from "../../../lib/reqlib";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
import {session} from "../../../lib/usertypes";
import DraggableSchedule from "../../../components/tutor/draggableschedule";
import TimezoneSelect from "react-timezone-select";
import {stringToOffset} from "../../../lib/timezonelib";
import Head from "next/head";
import {getTitle} from "../../../lib/headerlib";
import Notification from "react-notifications"

export default function WelcomeTutorSchedule() {
    const auth = useAuth();
    const router = useRouter();
    const welcomeRef = useRef<{ setIsLoading: (boolean) => void }>();
    const scheduleRef = useRef<{ getSessions: () => [session] }>();
    const [timezone, setTimezone] = useState<{ label: string, value: string }>({
        value: "America/Detroit",
        label: "(GMT-4:00) Eastern Time (US and Canada)",
    });

    function onSubmit(e) {
        e && e.preventDefault();

        const offsetFinal: number = stringToOffset(timezone.label);

        const selectedSessions = scheduleRef.current.getSessions().slice(0).filter(s => s.selected);

        let scheduleObj = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            let dayScheduleObj = [];
            const daySessions = selectedSessions.slice(0).filter(s => (s.day + 6) % 7 === i);
            for (const session of daySessions) {
                dayScheduleObj.push({
                    "offset": session.time * 60,
                    "duration": 0.5 * 60
                })
            }
            scheduleObj.push({
                "schedule": dayScheduleObj
            });
        }

        post(`tutor/update`, null, {
            "id": auth.userInfo.user_id,
            "default_schedule": {
                "schedule": scheduleObj,
            },
            "timezone_offset": offsetFinal,
        }, auth).then(() => {
            let newProfileInfo = auth.getProfileInfo();
            newProfileInfo["default_schedule"]["schedule"] = scheduleObj;
            auth.updateProfileInfo(newProfileInfo);
            router.push("/tutor/welcome/w9");
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{getTitle("Set schedule")}</title>
            </Head>
            <Welcome backlink="/tutor/welcome/subjects" nextfunc={onSubmit} ref={welcomeRef}>
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="tt-form">
                    <label className="label">When are you available?</label>
                    <p className="support my-4">Clients will be able to book sessions with you during any slot you mark
                        as available. You can always change this later.</p>
                    <p className="support mb-8">Click and drag over time slots to mark them as either available
                        (highlighted) or unavailable (blank) for booking.</p>
                    <DraggableSchedule ref={scheduleRef}/>
                    <label className="label">What timezone are you in?</label>
                    <TimezoneSelect value={timezone} onChange={data => setTimezone(data)}/>
                </form>
            </Welcome>

            <Notification>You have surpassed the maximum hours this tutor is willing to work in a given period.</Notification>
            
        </>
    )
}
```

The error message is: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'schedule' of null
at eval (schedule.tsx?8f51:55)"

And in the console, this error occurs at the following line:

```
newProfileInfo["default_schedule"]["schedule"] = scheduleObj;
```

Any ideas for how to solve this?  I feel like the solution is so obvious, but I'm just missing something here.  Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check out this guide on asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular - you should provide a minimum reproducible example of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. As this question stands it's not clear which parts of the code are relevant and what libraries are in use. The error message is telling you that `newProfileInfo["default_schedule"]` is null, but that's as much as we can deduce.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the object **newProfileInfo["default_schedule"]**, seems like the object is null.

hence when you try to find "schedule" object is gives the error

Comment: Thanks so much, this actually solved it!  It seems that removing the ["schedule"] after ["default_schedule"] records the schedule properly and doesn't throw any errors.